# How to Repair Mac Boot Drive when not able to boot into Machine?

Tags: mac, partitioning, disk-utility

Disk Utility Failed with errors. Wanted to use commercial tools say Disk Warrior to repair the drive.

How to use these tools when MAC not is not booting up?

Comment: You can make a bootable USB stick from DiskWarrior [& many other Mac recovery utilities] - though, same as any disaster recovery plan, you really should have it in place **before** you need it. Now, you'll need another Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Take the disk out and connect it to another machine as an external. Repair or do a complete re-install.

Then investigate why the mac won't boot - do you get memory chimes for example.

Comment: Thanks, Mike is there any way I could repair it from Boot camp Windows 10 running on same machine?

Comment: I don't run bootcamp, but i would assume windows won't do the mac style formatting. But if you can get into bootcamp / windows then you should be able to get into the utilities on the mac side...

Comment: You might be able to access the utilities... but you won't be able to run them. That aside, never attempt any kind of disk or partition alteration of any kind from inside a Windows Boot Camp installation. Windows simply doesn't understand how it's fooled into thinking it's in charge & will do potentially irreparable damage to the partition map.